# Can HTML 5 drag-and-drop handle folders?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, gmail

I'm impressed by Gmail's ability to let you drag files into emails for attachments, but when I try to drag a folder onto it, it says the file has 0 bytes. Is this a Gmail limitation, or is this something that's fundamentally not doable with the current HTML 5 spec?

Comment: You actually can drag folders, but you can't read any data from the contained files. In Safari you'll get clipboard data with type text/uri-list that you can use to figure out what the path of the folder is, but that's about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now directory upload available on chrome

you can select directory using input type

```
<input type='file' webkitdirectory >
```

and you can drag drop a folder

```
<div id="dropzone"></div>

var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
  var length = e.dataTransfer.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var entry = e.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (entry.isFile) {
      ... // do whatever you want
    } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
      ... // do whatever you want
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: the id for the div has some weird curly quotes. I was wondering why it wasn't working when i pasted it on my editor.

Answer (score 3):

The current [draft of html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-files) only supports a file list object for handling the 
getData events. so you can drag multiple files to a drag target but no folders

Comment: Wouldn't it be straightforward to implement a "list of files" that are the recursed files of a folder? (I mean straightforward for browser vendors, I understand this is not implementable by javascript currently)